# Sending Firefox Profile to Sauce Labs from CloudBees

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cloudbees, saucelabs

I have a Selenium test which requires a custom firefox profile to be uploaded to Sauce Labs. I have the file uploaded to the file sharing repository as referenced here on the cloudbees site:

https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/438491-sharing-files-with-build-executors-such-as-maven-settings-xml

I have enabled Sauce Connect in my Jenkins job and have the user and api key configured as well. I have also added the configuraton for the custom firefox profile usage on sauce labs

http://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config

using the setCapability method like so:

```
capabilities.setCapability("firefox-profile-url","https://repository-myProfile.forge.cloudbees.com/private/ffprofile/sauce.zip");
```

However it appears the file is not transferring as I thought it would. Is Sauce Connect somehow not communicating to CloudBees and accessing the file via the URL? Is there any other way I can get the firefox profile to Sauce Labs for use within my test?